# NGINX Error: upstream sent invalid chunked response while reading upstream

Tags: tomcat, nginx, jersey, chunked-encoding

We have tomcat with Jersey serving APIs behind NGINX.
A new streaming API we have developed worked great when we call Tomcat directly, but started getting no response when calling it through NGINX.

Looking at NGINX logs we got:

`upstream sent invalid chunked response while reading upstream`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We have solved the issue by adding the following to NGINX:

proxy_http_version 1.1

I guess NGINX proxies traffic by default with http version 1.0, but chunked transfer encoding is a http 1.1 feature.

https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,247883,247906#msg-247906

Comment: This answer already saved my life twice. I always forget what is the cause of this issue and end up here to remember.

Comment: Ha ha... I added it here due to selfish reasons, I knew I will need it in the future and will search for an answer in StackOverflow :-)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, only setting proxy_http_version 1.1 did not work. I had to set these -

```
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Connection "";
```

Comment: Why Connection header should be blank, excuse me?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `proxy_http_version 1.1`,

> This directive appeared in version 1.1.4.
> Sets the HTTP protocol version for proxying. By default, version 1.0 is used. Version 1.1 is recommended for use with keepalive connections and NTLM authentication.

Best way, Create a `http_proxy.conf` file and include it in your server config:

```
## http_proxy.conf
proxy_buffers           32 4k;
proxy_http_version      1.1;
proxy_send_timeout      60;
proxy_read_timeout      60;
proxy_connect_timeout   60;
proxy_set_header    Connection    '';
#proxy_set_header   HEADER_NAME   $VALUE;

## server.conf
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.domain.com
  include /etc/nginx/http_proxy.conf;    
  #.....
}
```